# jenkins using 2 git repositories, build android apk in one and run maven tests on the other

Tags: android, git, maven, jenkins, gradle

As the title shows, i'am using jenkins to perform continious integration for Appium Android tests.
My appium project is independent from the android application project. So in jenkins i checkout both from two different git repositories.
In my root folder I have Appium test project, and i have a sub-folder named "androidApp" containing the android application source code.

During build, i'm invoking gradle under the sub folder "androidApp" to build the apk file, and i'm invoking a shell script to perform maven test command.

as a result, gradle is building successfully, apk file is generated and then the mvn command seems to be aborted and test are not executed but the status of build is seccessful.

here is my stack trace:

```
:app:mergeMyAppPreprodJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForMyAppPreprod
:app:validateSigningLekioskPreprod
:app:packageMyAppPreprod
:app:assembleMyAppPreprod

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 17.14 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon:https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/8l/g1pnsm_j1z3b58rf61962m_m0000gn/T/hudson1923481353510535656.sh
+ sleep 80
+ emulator -avd Android_Emulator_5
+ appium -a 127.0.0.1
emulator: WARNING: Camera name 'webcam0' is not found in the list of connected cameras.
Use '-webcam-list' emulator option to obtain the list of connected camera names.

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: '127.0.0.1'
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
+ mvn clean test
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it around by adding a timeout of 10 seconds after gradle build. It seems that this timeout allows the mvn command to be run.